# Laravel 5: one form to update 2 linked tables. How to?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have the 2 simple tables below:

```
CUSTOMERS
id, email

CLAIMS
id, customer_id(fk), description
```

I created the related models (`Customers.php` and `Claims.php`) and set-up relationships: `hasOne()` and `belongsTo()`.

I also have my related `RESTful` controllers ready: `CustomersController.php` and `ClaimsController.php`.

What would be the best solution if I need to create/update records in both tables by submitting one form? Create one general controller? Mix models?

I have been searching in Laravel docs and on Google and still have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Controllers don't need to have a one-to-one relationship to models. Creating a customer in `ClaimsController` when necessary is just fine.

Comment: Why don't people like using the answer button these days. "Controllers don't need to have a one-to-one relationship to models. Creating a customer in ClaimsController when necessary is just fine." is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer model

```
public function claims(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Claims');
}
```

Claims model

```
public function customer(){                             
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

Now in controller u need to send request in store action

Something like this

```
class CreateCustomerClaim extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required',
            'description'=> 'required'

        ];
    }
}
```

Now in store action send your request, grab data from request and insert it in db

```
public function store(CreateCustomerClainsRextends $request)
{
    //example
    $customer= new Customer($request->all());

    Auth::user()->claims()->save($customer);

}
```

if u need to update use same request in update function, when u grab data from request just use update. Here is example where i update 3 different tables from one request

```
public function update($id,ArtikalUpdateRequest $request)
{
    $article = Artikal::findOrFail($id);
    if($article !== null){

        $article->update($request->all());

        \DB::table('artikal_podkategorija')
            ->where('artikal_id', $article->id)
            ->update(array('podkategorija_id' => $request['podkategorija']));

        \DB::table('arikalslike')
            ->where('artikal_id', $article->id)
            ->update(array('NazivSlike' => $request['NazivSlike']));

        $slika =   \DB::table('arikalslike')
            ->where('artikal_id', $article->id)->first();



        $image = Request::file('image');
        //dd($image);

        if($image != null){

            $destinationPath = 'uploads/artiklislike/';


            $thumb = $slika->SifraSlike;
            $fileName = $thumb;
            $nazivthumb =  $slika->NazivThumb;


            $slika->NazivSlike = $request['NazivSlike'];
            $slika->NazivThumb =  $nazivthumb;
            $slika->SifraSlike = $fileName;
            $slika->artikal_id = $article->id;


            //Snima sliku

            $img = Image::make(Input::file('image'));
            $destinationPath = $destinationPath.$fileName;
            Image::make($img)->save($destinationPath);

            // Snima sliku u manjem formatu thumb

            $destinationPath = 'uploads/artiklislike/';
            $img = Image::make(Input::file('image'));
            $destinationPath = $destinationPath.$nazivthumb;
            Image::make($img)->resize(300, 200)->save($destinationPath);
        }
    }

    return redirect('artikli')->with(['flash_message' => 'Uspiješno ste obrisali artikal!']);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the model inside your controllers like that. Inject your dependencies.